# How do we relate the exterior derivative of a scalar function to the "differential?"

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis

So Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* says that the exterior derivative of a $0$-form (scalar function) $f$ is a $1$-form, 
$$df_x (v) = \nabla f \cdot v\tag{1}$$
which is just a functional, and the domain is that $v$ must be in the tangent space about $x$.

But back in the regular multivariate calculus world, I see people define the "differential" of $f$ by $$df = \frac{df}{dx}dx + \frac{df}{dy}dy = \nabla f \cdot \left<dx,dy\right>\tag{2}$$

I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between (1) and (2). In (1), $v$ can be any element of the tangent space, whereas in (2) it seems that people are restricting $v$ to be some kind of differential step...?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Think of $x^i$ as a function that takes a point and returns its $i$th coordinate in the chosen basis. How might you then interpret $dx^i$?

Comment: I understand that $dx^i(x; v)$ is then effectively the ith element of the dual basis of $R^n$ acting on vectors v in the tangent space about x, but there’s still this level of arbitrariness in the choice of v that makes me unsure how we rigorously go from (1) to (2).

Comment: (2) is basically an application of the chain rule.

Comment: Uh, but there's still a degree of arbitrariness present because the $dx^i (x;v)$ can be a function of *any* v in the tangent space about x, right?

Comment: You’re doing a bit of apples/oranges comparison: (1) shows how to evaluate $df_x$ at an arbitrary $v$ in the tangent space, but that’s not what the expression for (2) is. Apply that functional to the same arbitrary tangent vector and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to think of $df$ as the dot product of $\nabla f$ with a vector of differentials $\left<dx,dy\right>$.  Instead, think of $dx$ and $dy$ as the dual basis to the standard basis vectors $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$.  In other words,
\begin{align*}
    dx(a\mathbf{i} + b\mathbf{j}) &= a \\
    dy(a\mathbf{i} + b\mathbf{j}) &= b
\end{align*}
Then $df_{(x,y)}$ is a dual vector whose coefficients are $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$.  It acts on vectors $v=a\mathbf{i} + b\mathbf{j}$ as
$$
    df(v) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\right)(a\mathbf{i} + b\mathbf{j}) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}b
$$
So you see that this is really the same thing as $\nabla f \cdot v$.

The differential one is the more “natural” of the two because it uses dual vectors rather than the dot product.  On a general Riemannian manifold with inner product $g$, the gradient operator can be *defined* by the equation
$$
    df(v) = g(\nabla f,v)
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So I understood the initial $dx^i (x;v)$ in (1) as elements of the dual basis of $R^n$, and while I'm happy to also interpret dx and dy themselves as still being the dual basis, but I'm still a bit confused as to where the infinitesimal-ness comes from. If dx and dy are still just functionals in the dual basis, then can't we still just plug in any arbitrary vector v from the tangent space?

Comment: Sure, we can plug them into the dual vector $df$.  The way you wrote (1) and (2), and your comment here, sounds like you're comparing $\nabla f \cdot v$ to $df$.  Really, you want to compare $\nabla f$ and $df$.  One is a vector that you can dot with $v$, one is a dual vector (covector) into which you can plug in $v$.